# $2$ questions about kernel density estimation with a kernel from a parametric family

Tags: references, kernel-smoothing, nonparametric

In kernel density estimation one has to choose a kernel $K_h$. Suppose that we choose a kernel from a family $\mathscr G_{\theta,h}$ parametrised by $(\theta,h)$.

Naturally $K_{\theta,h}$ now depends on both $\theta$ and $h$, and so the specific choice of parameters is important to motivate the questions:

1. Are there any references that explore a similar estimation problem, or the use of a kernel with additional parameters?
2. As I am only interested in the density estimate at a specific $x_0$, is there a reasonable justification in choosing $(\theta,h)$ that maximize some function of $\hat f(x_0;\theta,h)$, e.g.
   $$(\hat \theta,\hat h)=\arg\max_{\theta,h}\hat f(x_0;\theta,h)?$$